# I need help executing an if-function - My "if-function" executes, as well as my "else-function"?

Tags: javascript

Hi have this code below to check whether the first letter is a vowel or a consonant. If it is a vowel, you take the word and add "way" to the end. If it is a consonant, it moves the first letter to the end and suffixes an "ay" For some reason, when it is a vowel, it executes my else function? Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

  for (i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(0) === vowels[i]) {
      return str += "way";
    } else {
      var first = str.charAt(0);
      return str.substr(1, str.length) + first;
    }
  }
}

console.log( translatePigLatin("eight") );
```

Comment: You're returning inside a `for` loop. Stick a `debugger;` statement in there and watch what happens.

Comment: Please [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It should be easy to understand what's happening with some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and even more clear if you use a debugger to step through the code line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get "ighte" instead of "eightway" is the first time your loop runs, you're comparing the first letter of the string ("e") with the first vowel in your `vowels` array ("a").

You can do without the `for` loop by using `includes()`.

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(str.charAt(0))) {
    return str += "way";
  }
  else {
    var first = str.charAt(0);
    return str.substr(1, str.length) + first;
  }
}
```

If your intention with the `for` loop was to keep iterating the function until it encounters a vowel, then we can use this:

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(str.charAt(i))) {
      return str += "way";
    }
    else {
      var first = str.charAt(0);
      str = str.substr(1, str.length) + first;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this answers my question. I also understand how I was messing up my for loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop will only ever run once as even if your first condition fails your `else` will be taken and therefore it will return. Consider moving the `else` logic from the loop.

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

  for (i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(0) === vowels[i]) {
      return str += "way";
    }
  }

  var first = str.charAt(0);
  return str.substr(1, str.length) + first + "ay";
}

console.log( translatePigLatin("eight") );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried returning outside of the for loop, but then I just get "str". I am busy with an online course, so I don't have the option for debugging. I know this is probably a newbie question, but I am just trying to get my head around it.

Comment: What do you mean you just get "str"? Have you tried like above?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because, if condition checks for 'a' as the first vowel of the word and if the character does not match it goes to else statement. Hence here rest of the vowels are not being checked, Ideal way would be to first check for all vowels and then do else part below is the code

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  var first = str.charAt(0);
  for (i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
    if (first === vowels[i]) {
      return str += "way";
    } 
  }
  return str.substr(1, str.length) + first;
}

console.log( translatePigLatin("eight") );
```

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
    var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    var firstVowel = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(0) === vowels[i]) {
            firstVowel = true;
        }
    }

    if (firstVowel) {
        return str += "way";
    } else {
        var first = str.charAt(0);
        return str.substr(1, str.length) + first + "ay";
    }
}

console.log( translatePigLatin("eight") );
console.log( translatePigLatin("run") );
```